# Как применить функцию ко всем строкам?

Tags: python, алгоритм, pandas, numpy

Есть класс, в нем первый метод получает на вход два вектора (в виде пандас фреймов или нумпай матриц), хитрым способом обрабатывает их и на выходе выдает кортеж из 2 элементов. Этот метод уже написан.

Второй метод класса получает на вход вектор `Y` и массив `X` (не вектор, в нем неизвестное количество столбцов). Этот метод должен вызывать первый метод, давать ему на вход вектор `Y` и поочередно каждый столбец матрицы `X`, получать на выходе кортежи из двух элементов и заполнять ими нумпаевскую матрицу (количество строк этой матрицы равно количеству столбцов матрицы `X`, количество столбцов этой матрицы равно 2, при инициализации я предполагаю заполнить ее `np.nan`, а затем перезаполнить).

Безусловно реализовать функционал второго метода можно просто через цикл по каждому столбцу массива `X`. Однако не хотелось бы использовать цикл. Я подумал, может как то это сделать через `pandas.apply` (предварительно переведя все получаемые на вход объекты в пандас фреймы) или `numpy.apply_along_axis`, или может другие варианты есть. То есть использовать функционал, который в каждую строку нумпаевской матрицы вписывает нужные значения используя нужный столбец массива `Х`.

Comment: вам в вопросе нужно было указать исходные данные, желаемый результат и краткие тезисы, а не соревноваться с Маркесом в эпистолярном жанре. tldr, короче

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго пробивался через ваше описание, пытаясь понять, что-же вы хотите.
Не уверен что в итоге понял вас правильно, но понял вот так: есть матрица и вектор, и надо над каждым подбъектом (вектором) из X выполнить какую-то функцию, используя Y. Что там в итоге получиться -  скаляр, кортеж, или какой иной объект - не важно.

```
import numpy as np
def myfunc(a, b):
    return a*b
vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)
X=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).reshape(-1,3)
Y=np.array([5,6,7])
print ('X \n',X)
print ('Y \n',Y)
print ('X$Y \n',vfunc(X, Y))
```

Результат:

```
X 
 [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]

Y 
 [5 6 7]

X$Y 
 [[ 5 12 21]
 [20 30 42]
 [35 48 63]]
```

Тут в X$Y каждый подобъект  - результат применения функции `myfunc` к очередному подобъекту объекта X и вектора Y. Как вы и требовали -  от количества подобъектов в X и в Y скрипт не зависит. А вот если формат входных или выходных данных не тот, которые понят после расшифровки вашего описания - надеюсь подправить под ваши потребности сумеете самостоятельно.